# invalid literal for int() with base ten in listAPI view django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a view in django rest framework. In this view it takes an argument `city` to then fetch a list a neighborhoods in that city.

the example of the url looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/neighborhood-list/chicago/
```

the url code looks like this:

```
url(r'neighborhood-list/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)/', VenueFilterOptionsView.as_view()),
```

the view:

```
class NeighborhoodListView(generics.ListAPIView):
lookup_field = 'city'

def list(self, request, city):
    self.city = city
    queryset = Neighborhood.objects.filter(city=self.city)
    serializer = NeighborhoodSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

the serializer:

```
class NeighborhoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Neighborhood
        fields = 'neighborhood'
```

the model:

```
class  Neighborhood(models.Model):
city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)
neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
```

what I don't understand is I set the lookup field to city, unless that only works for instances not lists? And even so I am using the `listAPIView` generic

the exception location is here:

```
    /home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 966
```

and the code on line 966 is the following:

```
def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(AutoField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if value is None:
            return None
        return int(value)
```

the return value of this method in the **init** folder being referenced by the stack trace is being cast as an int every time. SO I guess now the question is how do we override this nonsense or work around it.

so now  I am working my way back trying to figure out what is going on.

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update - My original answer was incorrect.  List view doesn't actually work with the `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` attributes, those attributes are used by Rest Frameworks DetailView in the `get_object(self)` method to retrieve a *single instance* using those lookup fields.

I've updated the answer so it overrides the `get_queryset(self)` method to return the correctly filtered list.  This is how ListView should be customised.

---

It looks like you haven't defined your ListView properly.  The problem seems to be that you are trying to filter on the Cities Primary Key, which is an integer field, using a string that can't be parsed as an integer.  I'll write up how I think your view should look presuming your trying to do your filtering based on some field on the City model.

```
# models.py
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Neighbourhood(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

# views.py
class NeighbourhoodListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Neighbourhood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NeighbourhoodSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(city__name=self.kwargs.get('city')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^neighbourhood-list/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)/$',
        NeighbourhoodListView.as_view(),
        name='neighbourhood-list',
    )
]
```

This will filter your Neighbourhoods by the Cities name.  If you want to filter Neighbourhoods by the cities Primary Key, then you should use:

```
# views.py
class NeighbourhoodListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Neighbourhood.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NeighbourhoodSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(city=self.kwargs.get('city'))

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^neighbourhood-list/(?P<city>\d+)/$',
        NeighbourhoodListView.as_view(),
        name='neighbourhood-list',
    )
]
```

This fixes the view and url's to filter Neighbourhoods by the Cities Primary Key.  This would be more performant because it doesn't need to perform a join between City and Neighbourhood.