# django returning url kwarg string used for filtering as an int, trying to use as pk

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework, traceback

Observe the url below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/neighborhood-list/chicago/
```

this url is tied to a resource that will return a list of all the neighborhoods in a city.

However I am currently getting this error:

```
    invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'chicago'
Exception Location: /home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 966
```

line 966: `return int(value)`

Now I have already asked this question here: [invalid literal for int() with base ten in listAPI view django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339258/invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-ten-in-listapi-view-django-rest-framework)

and have implemented the suggestions but I am still fighting the django framework it seems. It looks like the Django framework is defaulting to trying to use my key word url agrument as a primary key

here is my url, view, serializer, and model code

url:

```
  url(r'^neighborhood-list/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', NeighborhoodListView.as_view(),
name='neighborhood-list',
    )
```

view:

```
class NeighborhoodListView(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Neighborhood.objects.all()
serializer_class = NeighborhoodSerializer(queryset, many=True)

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(city=self.kwargs.get('city'))
```

serializer:

```
class NeighborhoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Neighborhood
        fields = 'neighborhood'
```

model:

```
class  Neighborhood(models.Model):
city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)
neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
```

and if you so wish here is the full print out of the traceback which I think is going to be needed:

```
  Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/neighborhood-list/chicago/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'venue.apps.VenueConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get
  201.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/suitsandtables/venue/views.py" in get_queryset
  50.         return self.queryset.filter(city=self.kwargs.get('city'))

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  784.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  802.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1261.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1217.             condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  24.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  112.                 self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  966.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/neighborhood-list/chicago/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'chicago'
```

Comment: The error traceback does not match the code you have posted. In the traceback it says you are doing `neighborhood = Neighborhood.objects.filter(city= self.city)`.

Comment: You're not showing `VenueFilterOptionsView`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye omg thank you lol I'm using the wrong damn view! let me see

Comment: it looks like we still may have a problem. I need to see

Comment: ok I fixed it with the corrrect stack trace. The problem continues even though I have the correct view now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
self.queryset.filter(city=self.kwargs.get('city'))
```

`city` is a foreign key to `City`, which is matched by its `id` property (an integer). You are trying to match it with `'chicago'` which obviously fails as an integer, hence the exception.

You have two options here, either refer to the city name:

```
self.queryset.filter(city__name=self.kwargs.get('city'))
```

Or fetch the `City` object first:

```
city = City.objects.filter(name__contains=self.kwargs.get('city')).first()
self.queryset.filter(city=city)
```

I am using a `filter` here, a `.get()` would raise an exception if the city was not found.

Comment: ugh of course. and when I wrote my raw sql out I actually did name the city.name property just didn't think to cross it over. These simple issues man. Thank you